# Why, when checking compile-time constant, one branch is enough for resolving variable assignation, but is not enough for returning from that branch?

Tags: java, jls, compile-time-constant

We know, that if `if` statement's boolean expression/condition contains compile-time constant (or a variable, holding compile-time constant), then compiler can resolve this constant expression and:

```java
public void ctc1() {

    final int x = 1;
    String text;

    if (x > 0) text = "some text";

    System.out.println(text); //compiles fine, as compile-time constant is resolved during compilation phase;

}
```

would compile and work fine, without "variable might not have been initialized" compiler error. No initialisation of `text` in "else" branch (or after "if") is required, as compiler "understands" the constant is always going to result in `true`, while evaluating `x > 0` (which ends up being `1 > 0`).

Why, however, same resolution does not work (or works differently) when we want to return from the method, as:

```java
public int ctc2() {

    final int x = 1;

    if (x > 0) return 1;

    //requires another explicit "return" for any other condition, than x > 0

}
```

or, moreover, as:

```java
public int ctc2() {

    final int x = 1;

    if (1 > 0) return 1;

}
```

?

Why compiler cannot infer/understand/resolve absolutely identical semantics and cannot be sure, that the `return` is always executed and code is OK to be compiled?

In case of initialisation in the branch containing compile-time constant, compiler can resolve the constant value(s), and as it knows they will never change, it is sure, variable is going to be initialised. So, it allows usage of the variable after `if` statement.

Why resolving constant expression works differently for the `return` case, though? what is the point behind this difference/limitation?

To me, this looks like "two identical logical semantics" work differently.

I'm using:

```
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised the first one compiles. The answer is going to be "because the Java Language Specification says so", are you looking for references to that, or something deeper (like what technical limitation in the compiler might allow one but not the other, or the authors' intent)?

Comment: @kaya3 IFF the compiler is designed (and it is) in such a fashion, that values (or expressions) that are defined as compile-time constants, *are resolved* at compile time, then OK, that makes sense. But, why then *return* doesn't bear the same language semantics?

Comment: "Why" could mean several different things here, depending on how deep you want to go. The plain answer is because the JLS says so, but I'm going to guess that isn't satisfying.

Comment: @kaya3 then I would have not asked this question here... "because it's so" is certainly not enough to be the answer.

Comment: You could have asked this question asking "why" in multiple different meanings, otherwise I would not be asking you for clarification.

Comment: See these two great answers by Eric Lippert to understand why "why" questions like these are not good questions: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585).

Comment: @Sweeper so, if there is some inconsistency (or something I don't understand yet) and I ask question about this, using the word "why", in my question - is this such a wrong and terrible thing? seriously? I would better concentrate on the question being asked, if wanted to help, rather than just rushing for finding excuses - why "why" questions are bad. And I completely disagree with that point, that "why" questions are bad.

Comment: Also, "*Is asking “why” on language specs still considered as “primary opinion-based” if it can have official answers?*" contains critical point: "if it can have official answers".. and I can't find any official answer clarifying the concept. If you can, kindly refer me to it.

Comment: We *are* concentrating on the question being asked, we are trying to get you to make the question specific enough that it can be answered without wasting a lot of time producing an answer that is not what you want. Because as written, there are multiple different things you *might* want by asking this question, and each of them would be a lot of work to write.

Comment: @kaya3 how else can I clarify this further? one branch is enough, for resolution by the compiler, and it won't complain about uninitialized variable.. and absolutely same logic doesn't work for "return".. How.. How else can this be further clarified?? rephrasing: compiler understands that the value, that is defined as constant expression, is ALWAYS going to evaluate your "if"'s condition to true.. hence, variable is always initialized. Why compiler doesn't do the same when I merely change initialization with returning?

Comment: Consider that I could have spent 10 minutes writing an answer with references to the parts of the JLS which specify these behaviours, but instead I spent 10 seconds writing a comment to check whether such an answer would be what you were looking for, and eventually you clarified that it would not. I have proposed at least two possibilities: are you asking what technical limitation of the compiler might require it to be this way, are you asking what the intentions of the language designers were when designing it this way, or something else? The Eric Lippert links have more possibilities still.

Comment: Nobody is asking you to clarify what language behaviour you are asking about, we are asking you to clarify what you mean by "why", because whenever a "why" question is answered directly, you can always keep asking "why" again to look for a deeper explanation. So how deep are you wanting to go with this?

Comment: "how else can I clarify this further?" You can find other ways you can ask this question in the first link I posted. That is, you should be specific about the kind of answers that you are looking for. Are you looking for the sections of the specification that specifies this behaviour? Are you looking for how this design is in line with Java's design principles? What kind of answer will satisfy you? If we don't know that, you _could_ just keep on asking "why" until the end of time.

Comment: I'm just in the arguments on *why I asked the question*, which is very clear and self-descriptive. With all respect, but I think that's just ranting about this question.. saying everything, **except** answering it. I have *already* said, that if you can provide a JLS - that's gonna be good, as I can't find anything about this differentiation. If you, on the other hand, can even explain why Java compiler has been designed so, it's even better. If you can't - just let others. Btw, there's nothing about "Java design principles".. it's rather a peculiarity of compiler.

Comment: I'm super interested in what *exactly* is not clear for whoever voted for closing this question.

Comment: We have explained *very precisely* what is not clear about your question. I've written over a thousand answers on Stack Overflow and Sweeper has written nearly 5000 answers; do you *really* think either of us prefer to pointlessly argue with people who ask questions instead of answering them? You are just complaining about being told that you need to explain your question better, instead of actually trying to understand how your question needs to be improved, or improving it.

Comment: @kaya3 no, you haven't explained anything clearly. That's just how *you* probably understand clarity. Btw, I've added to, extra-clarification questions at the bottom of the question. Does it read clearer, for you, now? maybe that's what you meant?..

Comment: This is a difference (mismatch? inconsistency?) between the rules around definite assignment and reachability, I think.

Comment: @AndyTurner sounds plausible.. yet, it's clearly semantics' inconsistency, I think.

Comment: you gotta love this twerks in the java compiler. it never sees to surprise you. interesting and weird question at the same time. I love it.

Comment: @Eugene thanks, dear Eugene. I think too, it's really interesting.. describing quite weird behaviour, yes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difference (mismatch? inconsistency?) between the rules around definite assignment and the particular normal completion rules of the if statement.

Specifically, the [definite assignment rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-16.html) say:

> In all, there are four possibilities for a variable V after a statement or expression has been executed:
>
> - V is definitely assigned and is not definitely unassigned.
>
>   (The flow analysis rules prove that an assignment to V has occurred.)
> - ...

The "flow analysis rules" are not clearly specified with regard to branch pruning, but it doesn't seem unreasonable to assume that the flow analysis is able to take into account constant values when deciding whether to follow a branch, meaning it is able to determine there is only one of the 4 states possible (definitely assigned after the if statement).

However, the [reachability rules for an if statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22) say that:

> An if-then statement can complete normally iff it is reachable.

Nothing about the expression value or flow analysis here. It's perhaps worth pointing out that this is itself different to the reachability rules for `while`, `do` and basic `for` loops, which do explicitly mention the case of a constant true expression. Any of these returns would be accepted in `ctc2()`:

```
while (true) return 1;
do { return 1; } while (true);
for (;;) return 1;
```

So, the language is specified in such a way that it overlooks the fact that your if statement cannot complete normally because of a) the constant expression, b) the return statement, despite that being "obvious" to a human reader.

---

An example of this difference actually being desirable (or, at least, the reachability rules being desirable) is if you have a `DEBUG` boolean (as in, a constant-valued to trigger debug-only behaviour). You can imagine a method something like:

```
if (!DEBUG) {
  return value;
}
return otherValue;
```

If the "conditional" return were treated in the same way as definite assignment, at least one of the return statements unreachable.

This would be a pain for debugging-time alternate behaviour like this.

Ofc one might argue that you could instead do something that isn't compile-time constant, e.g. invoke a method. I guess you can do that, but I would argue that not allowing use of the dirt-simplest method is.... unnecessarily restrictive, for the sake of avoiding a pretty rare "head-scratcher" in code.

Comment: The rules for `if` statements don't mention anything about when the condition is a constant expression, so [this section is also relevant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.1.1), specifically *"V is [un]assigned after any constant expression (§15.29) whose value is `true` when false."*.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy for your answer. I just have some busy time now, and will definitely examine this answer a bit later.